# Intersection between sets containing different types of variables

Tags: c#, collections

Let's assume we have two collections:

```
List<double> values
List<SomePoint> points
```

where `SomePoint` is a type containing three coordinates of the point:

```
SomePoint
{
 double X;
 double Y;
 double Z;
}
```

Now, I would like to perform the intersection between these two collections to find out for which points in `points` the `z` coordinate is eqal to one of the elements of `values`

I created something like that:

```
HashSet<double> hash = new HashSet<double>(points.Select(p=>p.Z));
hash.IntersectWith(values);
var result = new List<SomePoints>();
foreach(var h in hash)
    result.Add(points.Find(p => p.Z == h));
```

But it won't return these points for which there is the same `Z` value, but different `X` and `Y`. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashSet<double> values = ...;
IEnumerable<SomePoint> points = ...;

var result = points.Where(point => values.Contains(point.Z));
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you not just do

```
var query = (from d in values
            join p in points
            on d equals p.Z
            select p).ToList();
```

?